# Microsoft.Office.Interop - ReplaceText (with) *NewLine* in Word.Table

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I am having an application that uses Microsoft Word 2016 / the Interop interface to call the `replace` function. This way the application replaces some texts like 'Customername' to the actual name of the customer. Surely this is not the best way to do so, but thats how the application was build back in the days. Now I have to do some adjustments to the formatting facing a problem with the named function.

One of the Texts getting replaced is "[*TELNR*]" , beeing replaced with all known numbers of the customer, one number per line. Inserting New Lines as `vbCr` works great on a blank page as you can see top of the screenshot. The same called function will not put a new lines into a table (second page on the left) and won't even touch a textbox (second page on the right).

I have tried passing Line breaks as `^p`, `\n\r`, `\n`, `vbClRf` / `vbNewLine`, `vbCr`. None of these will work.

I haven't found anything usefull on google or SO. Do you have ideas or a reason what might cause or even solve the problem?

```
#Region "Sample Strings"
    Dim sample1 As String = "t:022220000000" & vbNewLine & "h:022221111111" & vbNewLine & ":0222222222222" & vbNewLine & "f:022223333333"
    Dim sample2 As String = "t:022220000000" & vbCr & "h:022221111111" & vbCr & ":0222222222222" & vbCr & "f:022223333333"
    Dim sample3 As String = "t:022220000000" & "^p" & "h:022221111111" & "^p" & ":0222222222222" & "^p" & "f:022223333333"
    Dim sample4 As String = "t:022220000000" & "\n" & "h:022221111111" & "\n" & ":0222222222222" & "\n" & "f:022223333333"
    Dim sample5 As String = "t:022220000000" & "\n\r" & "h:022221111111" & "\n\r" & ":0222222222222" & "\n\r" & "f:022223333333"
    Dim sample6 As String = "t:022220000000" & vbCrLf & "h:022221111111" & vbCrLf & ":0222222222222" & vbCrLf & "f:022223333333"
#End Region
Private Sub replaceText(file As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, find As String, replaceWith As String)
    // First line was commented out for the ^p try
    If replaceWith.Contains("^") Then replaceWith = replaceWith.Replace("^", "")
    file.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:=find, ReplaceWith:=replaceWith, Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

The following was function was used to insert the textbox.
[image: Simple Text Box]

Comment: RE: the textboxes -- I don't think they are part of the `Content` of the document; I think you'll have to iterate through all the `Shapes` in the document and replace the text in each one individually.

Comment: I agree with @ZevSpitz analysis of why your code isn't working with text boxes - *assuming* these are drawing object text boxes, which isn't clear from the information you give us (although likely, given your code isn't affecting their content). Can you describe HOW such a text box is created in the document? Or can it be dragged, like a graphic?

Comment: Of all the "new line" things you've tried, the only one that would / should / could work with vb.net is `vbCr`, which forces a *new paragraph*, not a new line. `vbCr`is ANSI 13; a new line is ANSI 11, so Chr(11) should also work. (A new line is probably what's wanted, not a new paragraph.)

Comment: All that said, there should be no problem inserting Chr(13) or Chr(11) into a table. Is there anything special about this table? Are these *content controls*? Is it possible that this is a "plain text" content control?

Comment: I tried replacing (in VBA; Word 2010) with `Chr(13)`. The text outside the table was replaced properly, but within the table I got some extra whitespace instead. Replacing with `^p` as part of the string worked just fine for both. I don't think there should be a difference between VBA and VB.NET in this case. Also, I seem to recall that `Find` doesn't override options set in the UI; perhaps you need to explicitly pass in the `MatchWildcards` parameter?

Comment: @Cindy Meister  New line it's ASCII 10 (vbLf, ChrW(10)). ASCII 11 it's a Vertical Tab. [ANSI Table](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-codes.php).

Comment: @Jimi Not in Word... In Word ANSI 10 is meaningless.

Comment: @Cindy Meister  Might be meaningless in Word, but *a new line is ANSI 11* conveys a wrong concept, IMO. Something like: In Word a vertical tab ChrW(11) is intepreted as a line break. I would suggest `^l` (lowercase L) to force it (like `SHIFT+ENTER`).

Comment: @CindyMeister I edited the post to show how the textbox was inserted. I found out, that accessing the textbox is done by accessing the Shapes, as Zev Spitz mentioned. `Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name` for example to rename them. I am now having troubles to figure a way to automatically access it from vb.net (The shown way uses the selection). Any hints? The Table has default settings. Only change was made to avoid rescaling (to much text will not change the table / cell sizes)

Comment: @ZevSpitz I got it working with `^p` and `^l` (Both do work). It did not work for me, because there was no space before `^p` (see sample strings) (`222^p` instead of `222 ^p`). I am still wondering, why vbCr works for the blankpage but not for the table... ideas?

Comment: Note that `^p` and `^l` are inserting two different things -- `^p` is a new paragraph, while `^l` is forcing an end of line, even in the middle of a paragraph. You can see the difference if you justify the paragraph; the last line of the paragraph will be left-aligned, but the words before the line break will be spread out across the width of the paragraph.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Thank you. I'll be using `^l`, since it's like Shift-Enter. Also, as a little OT information; I am now at least allowing users to also work with bookmarks which enables them to have more then 255 characters (replace-function char limit) in an "autotext". It was quite easy to complete that in my replaceText-Function.